# Need Batch File to Find Particular string in notepad

Tags: sql, batch-file

I need to automate one process ,actually i have one text file which contains some sql statements like

```
update employee set sal=200 
delete from employee where emplid=500
select * from employee
```

if it is update or  delete statement have to find the employee (table name ) and it shuld write to other notepad file.

Any suggestions.

Comment: @Gidil do you think your edit is valid? I couldn't make out from the OP if the statements where layout in the text file like that...

Comment: @rene, it doesn't make a difference in the batch file one way or another. For the post on the other hand, it is much easier to read and understand a clearly layed out set of queries.

Comment: @Gidil We disagree on that...the question is not about the actual queries nor to understand them...how they are layout in the file is important though...We have to wait for the OP to clear this out...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is called `sql.txt` AND your statements are all on one single line the tool [`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) can do the trick:

```
findstr /r "^update.*employee ^delete.*employee" sql.txt
```

for this input:

```
update employee set sal=200   
delete from employee where emplid=500
select * from employee
```

This will be the result

```
update employee set sal=200 
delete from employee where emplid=500
```

to store your results in a file add a redirect at the end of the command `> employee.sql`